# Null Exception when recording using mediaRecorder

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, mediarecorder

I am doing an call recording application. My problem is that the recording works fine when a call is received but it does not stop recording. My code and the logcat are below. Any form of help is greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
    public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if(null == bundle)
                    return;
            String state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
            {
            }
            else if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                Log.i("TelephonyManager", "Call picked up");
                mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
                mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
                mRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/Recording/callrecord.mp4");
                try{
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                }
                mRecorder.start();
                Log.i("StartRecordingCall", "Recording Call end");
            }
            else if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                Log.i("TelephonyManager", "Call hunged up");
                mRecorder.stop();
                mRecorder.release();
                mRecorder=null;
            }
    }
```

}
LogCat

```
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/MediaRecorder(2831): stop called in an invalid state: 1
12-11 22:53:51.502: D/AndroidRuntime(2831): Shutting down VM
12-11 22:53:51.502: W/dalvikvm(2831): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b544300)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.callrecorder.IncomingCallReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2362)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:142)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at com.example.callrecorder.IncomingCallReceiver.onReceive(IncomingCallReceiver.java:63)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2355)
12-11 22:53:51.502: E/AndroidRuntime(2831): ... 10 more
```

Comment: The log indicates that you're trying to stop the mediarecorder while it's in an IDLE state. This suggests that you're either calling `stop` on a newly created mediarecorder (that hasn't been started), or twice in a row on the same mediaplayer.

Comment: It seems that once i end the call and enter the TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE state, mRecorder cannot be found. Exception is thrown when mRecorder.stop() is called.

Comment: The BroadcastReceiver documentation states that "A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.". So I'd recommend you to place `mRecorder` in an outer class, or to make it static.

Comment: thanks Michael. Making mRecorder static solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK` fired when we cut or end the call and you started recording in that.

And `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` will fired when you pick the call and this will fire before `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK` and in `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` state you are accessing mRecorder.stop(); which is null... and not initialized.

And your mRecorder should also be static since BroadcastReceiver calls multiple for different events.

Comment: Actually `OFFHOOK = The phone is off hook. At least one call exists that is dialing, active or holding and no calls are ringing or waiting.`  See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/Phone.java#Phone.State.0OFFHOOK