# Media Recorder stop() is never called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-mediarecorder

I am recording an audio file on my broadcast but I am not getting any error but my recorder.stop() is never called heres my code:

```
String file_name= "recording";
        audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".3gp", sampleDir);
        String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        //recorder = null;

         int audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL;

         recorder.setAudioSource(audioSource);
         recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
         recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
         recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath()); 


             recorder.prepare();

             recorder.start();
```

and my stop function contains:

```
public void stopRecord()throws IOException{
             if(recorder!=null)
             {

             recorder.stop();

             recorder.release();
             recorder.reset();

             Log.d(TAG, "recording stopped");
             }
             else
             {
                 Log.d(TAG, "recording stopped error");
             }
```

i am calling start recorder at offhook stage and stop recorder at idle ,but it goes to idle state and stop is not called at all .

```
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:  
                     prev_state=state;
                     Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_IDLE==>"+incoming_nr);

                     Log.d(TAG, "recording stopped");  // Executes till here and skips the below part
                     try {
                        stopRecord();
                         Log.d(TAG, "recording stopped");  
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                     Log.d(TAG, "recording stopped");
```

I have give all the permission required pls help me on this
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you get any exception?any errors?

Comment: no it shows nothing in logcat ,even if I place a log its skips it

Comment: How you are capturing the idle state. post that code also. I doubt its not identifying the idle state.

Comment: i have posted it now u can check that

Comment: please post the manifest file in which you have added the permissions :)

Comment: @Auto-Droid :Your try block is not getting executed. that means there is an error in the **stopRecord()** function. Check out the stacktrace being generated in the catch block.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` is called when there is no activity and this is called before `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK`.

Here you are calling `stopRecord()` function in the `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` state  and thus you are accessing `mRecorder.stop();`, but at that point Recorder object is null and not initialized. Checdk this post for more clarification [Null Exception when recording using mediaRecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13823445/1626878). Also check out the comments.

As far as no error is concerned, you are calling it in `try/catch` block. So only stack trace will be generated.

Comment: case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:  
                  prev_state=state;
 if((prev_state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)){  
                       prev_state=state;  
                        //Answered Call which is ended  
                       Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_IDLE==>"+incoming_nr);
                       Log.d(TAG, "recording stopped");  
                       try {stopRecord();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
                       Log.d(TAG, "recording stopped");

Comment: now i have checked the condition inside the idle state to stop recording but this give illegal state exception

Comment: thanks Sahil Mahajan Mj your link was good to direct me thanks again